# How can I extend syntax highlighting with my own keywords?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I already have syntax highlighting for javascript, but what I'd like to do is extend it with some additional rules.

What I've been trying to start, is using highlight "Prototype" with a cyan background.

I tried following some other answers, but they completely replace the syntax highlighting, but I want to simply add on to the current syntax highlighting.

Ideally this would be separated into their appropriate files, ie. highlighting rules in the syntax folder or whatever is appropriate.

---

This is what I currently have and it doesn't highlight `Prototype` on my `attack.js` file:

`~/.vim/syntax/js.vim`:

```
syn match sophiePrototype "Prototype"
highlight sophiePrototype ctermfg=cyan guifg=#00ffff
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The correct filetype for JavaScript is `javascript`, so your file, which corresponds to a non-existing `js` filetpe, will never be sourced automatically. It should be:

   ```
   ~/.vim/syntax/javascript.vim
   ```
2. Vim sources syntax scripts from three standard location in a specific order:

   ```
   ~/.vim/syntax/javascript.vim
   $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/javascript.vim
   ~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim
   ```

   Because you want your syntax highlighting to *extend* the existing one, you should use the last location:

   ```
   ~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim
   ```
3. Given your use case, `:help :syn-keyword` seems more appropriate than `:help :syn-match`.

   ```
   syn keyword sophiePrototype Prototype
   ```
4. It is considered best practice to separate the definition of the visual attributes of syntax highlighting from the definition of the highlight groups themselves.

   If your goal is to have `Prototype` marked as some kind of "keyword", then you should probably use the default `Keyword` highlight group, which is likely to already be handled by your colorscheme:

   ```
   syn keyword Keyword Prototype
   ```

   If your goal is to give your keywords their own highlight group while still having them look like an existing highlight group, you can use a link:

   ```
   syn keyword sophiePrototype Prototype
   highlight link sophiePrototype SomeOtherHighlightGroup
   ```

   If your goal is *really* to use a new highlight group that doesn't look like anything else for `Prototype`, then you should move that `:highlight` command to a proper colorscheme or, barring that, to your `vimrc`, as per `:help colorscheme-override`:

   ```
   augroup my_colorschemes
       autocmd!
       autocmd Colorscheme * highlight sophiePrototype ctermfg=cyan guifg=#00ffff
   augroup END
   ```

Comment: I was wondering why you hadn't answered this :-)

Comment: Wrong time zone ` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ `.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks!
It works as the question I asked.

Comment: One side question I have is, how do I "add-to" a "contains" list? I want to do "Prototype"  as something contained within a comment, but I don't want to remove the older "contains" items, like "TODO".

Comment: I tried `containedin` ie. `syn keyword Todo Research containedin=Comment contained`, but although TODO works again, "Research" no longer works. [yeah, sorry my keyword has changes to 'Research'] EDIT: I hadn't read tot he end of the help section on `containedin` to realize you also need `contained` still... so i added it. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, I have a "TODO" file with no file extension. How can i add syntax commands to that? I tried adding my commands to a file named ".vim" in `syntax`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Please ask separate questions. It will make things easier to handle for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is already pretty close. However, there are three minor issues with it:

1. The `filetype` for JavaScript is called "javascript", not "js". That's what your file is supposed to be called.
2. To change the **b**ackground, you would use the `*bg` options, i.e. `ctermbg` and `guibg`.
3. To extend default syntax highlighting rather than replacing it, put a file in your "after" directory as explained in `:help after-directory`. Vim will load regular JavaScript syntax first.

The following lines in `~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim` will highlight "Prototype" with a cyan background:

```
syn match sophiePrototype "Prototype"
highlight sophiePrototype ctermbg=cyan guibg=#00ffff
```

Comment: This was also helpful. It explains the errors I was making and some additional details.